# Using $.proxy with Kendo widgets produces memory leaks

Tags: kendo-ui

This is my first question to Stackoverflow, so I hope I'm doing it right:

I'm using Kendo Widgets extensively in my app. I use a custom wrapper for every Widget type ( MyAutocomplete,MyGrid, etc. ). Every wrapper passes proxy'ed functions to the widget's constructor:

```
 var me=this;
 $("#mywidget").kendoAutoComplete({
     ...
     dataTextField: me.dataTextField,
     select: $.proxy(me.onSelected, me),
     change: $.proxy(me.onChanged, me), 
 });
```

The wrapper has a dispose function that calls Kendo's 'destroy' method, Jquery's 'remove' and 'off' methods etc. .

Running my app produces serious memory leaks.
Using Chrome Dev Tools' Profiles tab I see the context for holding my wrapper is the proxy reference:

```
proxyjquery.js:775
function () {
            return fn.apply( context, args.concat( core_slice.call( arguments ) ) );
        }
```

I checked this by removing the proxy and passing the original event-handlers.
Although not functioning correctly ( of coarse ), the wrapper was no longer referenced.
What I think is this: .proxy is a closure to the original function ( e.g. me.onSelected ),
so the 'return fn.apply' is holding reference to the 'fn' which is 'me.onSelected'.

So the questions are: Am I right about the closure issue, and if so -

How do I clear references to event handlers which are proxy'ed?

Many thanks in advance.